# Ordenar minha flatList pela hora

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Estou filtrando minha flatlist pela data (period), mas quero colocar as horas em ordem crescente:

```
<FlatList
                style={{backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 10}}
                data={this.state.progr.data.filter(x => x.period === '2019-10-16T00:00:00.000-03:00')}
                renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem({item})}
                keyExtractor = {(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
            />
```

A hora que vem da api está com o nome:única coisa que importa aí é a hora que puxo da seguinte forma: {new Date(item.start_time).getHours()}

```
start_time: '019-09-12T14:00:00.000-03:00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir fazer da seguinte forma:

```
data={this.state.progr.data.sort((a, b) => a.start_time > b.start_time).filter(x => x.period === '2019-10-16T00:00:00.000-03:00')}
```